# Is this red habanero plant overwatered and how should I save it?

Tags: plant-health, watering, chili, repotting, habaneros

So I'm quite a newbie in gardening but I decided to plant a couple chilli plants for the summer because I was very interested.

This red habanero was planted about a week ago and been on slow decline. Right after I planted it there was a whole night and day of rain and I was dumb enough to leave it outside. The other two chilli plants next to it are still somewhat healthy and was either not as affected from the over watering or quickly recovered but when I got home today this habanero was suddenly extremely droopy.

It would be great if someone can confirm that the symptoms of the plant are overwatering and how I can help it recover. I've looked online and followed many of the steps but don't seem to be working. I've put holes in the soil, turned the soil to try and dry it out but nothing seems to work. I think the next step is to repot it into something else and leave it in the shade until it recovers but I don't want to minimise the plant getting hurt in the process and what not.

I'm really hoping for the guy to survive and any input should be great. Thanks in advance!

---

[image: Red habanero]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do no know if it over-watered. But if you are not sure, I really think it is one of the problems. They likes dry places. More dry more spicy, and the chilies have not so much water as tomatoes (same family).

Do no worry, it will not die, if it will not have water for one week or so (depending on your climate), and you will clearly see if it asks you for water.

I'm more in doubt about: too much fertilizer or wrong one (or maybe it is just the flash effect): leaves are particular glossy.

Additionally: they like a lot (really a lot) of sun.

So, stop watering. Water only when chili are asking for it. Note: the pot seems large, so a lot less concern about watering on the right moment: soil will keep some extra reserve.

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like this is planted in a plastic tub. Does it have drainage holes? If not, you should repot it into something more appropriate with drainage holes. No drainage will definitely contribute to water problems.

Answer (score 1):

When the habanero gets soak with water sitting in a pot it cannot absorb oxygen from the roots and excess water suffocates it. This is what I did to save my hananero get it off the ground and raise it up, make sure the drain holes are not clogged, apply a 1:1 of hydrogen peroxide and water solution directly to the soil and do not let the solution touch the leaves, 1:1 ration means 2 cups of 3% hydrogen peroxide to 2 cups of water in a gallon container, if you want to be on the safe side use 2 cups of hydrogen peroxide 3% with 3 cups of water. DO NOT THE PLANT FOR 3 DAYS, after 3 days resume watering you habanero plant with just 2 cups of water 2-3 week for a month, monitor the plant if it has revive and the leaves and stems are not dropping, monitor for root rot the leaves with turn brown if fungus sets in the leaves with turn black, if does repeat the procedure good luck.

Comment: Let me what happens.